# Unable to make ball jump and move same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to jump or move left/right any point in time. But unable to jump and at the same time move left/right simultaneously. Am I missing anything? My codes as follows. Thanks for advice.

```
public int rotationSpeed = 100;
public float jumpHeight = 8;

private bool isFalling = false;

void Update () {
    // handle ball rotation 
    float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
    rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.back * rotation);  

    //check input
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) 
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'd just like to add that it is right to use `AddForce`, or a variant, rather than setting velocity directly, due to all the physics calculations. But the reason it only jumps straight up is because you are setting the X and Z components to 0. If you used `rigidbody.velocity += new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0)` you would get a behaviour more closely resembling what you want. But I emphasise, still not the right way of doing it and you would still need a lot more work to get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in docs : [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly
you should use [AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) instead or [AddForceAtPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

EDIT :

Just to clarify why : 
Velocity is a calculated result of the different forces applied to your object, you CAN assign this value to force the calculus to not be used BUT you SHOULD NOT because adding forces together with the builtin AddForce is way more stable and clean,

in short if you assign to velocity you bypass every calculus you've done before if you use AddForce, as name states you add a new force to your forces sum

EDIT 2 :

```
void Update () {
    // handle ball rotation 
    float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
    rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.back * rotation);  

    //check input
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) 
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0) * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 8);   In this case, the ball doesn't even jump.

Comment: If ball does not jump it is because a force of 8 is smaller than Gravity which is -9.81 you have to apply a much stronger value to push your object up, as gravity is one of the forces in calculus think about the Newton apple

Comment: It was the force of the gravity giving the problem. I pushed the figure to 500 and it is bouncing fine. What I don't get is since the force is -9.81, shouldn't 10 be enough to make the ball jump just a little bit? Even at a 100, it barely jumps.

Comment: I think it should be enough physically but the thing is only if it is a continuous force but you must take account that you add your force of 10 only for one frame so it is only for a very short time and not powerful enough to fight against inertia, you need to apply this force for a long time to be able to actually feel it's effet OR set it to a very high value